# Performance issue while using C/OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp

I wrote some code to test executing time of small program using C and OpenMP and I encountered some issue with app execution time.
Here is pice of code, responsible to add 2 vectors:

```
  float *x_f = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * DATA_SIZE);
  float *y_f = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * DATA_SIZE);

  for (int i = 0; i < DATA_SIZE; i++) {

    x_f[i] = 1.0f;
    y_f[i] = 2.0f;
  }

  start_time = omp_get_wtime();

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(N_THREADS)
  {
      const int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();

      int begin = range * thread_id;
      int end = begin + range;
      if (thread_id + 1 == N_THREADS)
          end = DATA_SIZE;

      for (int i = begin; i < end; i++) {
          x_f[i] += y_f[i];
      }
  }
  end_time = omp_get_wtime();
  duration = end_time - start_time;
```

Same code I use to add vectors with double type elements - in the same application. Program seems to work fine, but results are a little strange for me, because float computation time is several times greater than double.

```
Float      1       2       3       4      5        6      7        8       9      10      11      12
1024    0,0036  0,4535  0,6875  0,9443  1,1653  1,5068  1,6951  2,0447  2,3546  2,6611  3,1319  3,1468
double     1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11     12
1024    0,0004  0,0014  0,0016  0,0019  0,0018  0,0018  0,002   0,0021  0,0024  0,0028  0,0045  0,0036
```

1-12 is number of OmpeMP Threads, 1024 is vector size in elements. Time is in msec. Can someone explain me, why it happened or what I am doing wrong? I am new in C and OpenMP and I have no idea, why results are as above.

EDIT: Full source code below:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  double start_time, end_time, duration;

  if (argv[1] == NULL || argv[2] == NULL) {
    printf("Error parsing data from input. Program will now close");
    return 2;
  }
  int DATA_SIZE = atoi(argv[1]);
  int N_THREADS = atoi(argv[2]);

  int range = DATA_SIZE / N_THREADS;

  // ===================== FLOAT ========================
  float *x_f = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * DATA_SIZE);
  float *y_f = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * DATA_SIZE);

  for (int i = 0; i < DATA_SIZE; i++) {

    x_f[i] = 1.0f;
    y_f[i] = 2.0f;
  }

  start_time = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(N_THREADS)
  {
    const int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();

    int begin = range * thread_id;
    int end = begin + range;
    if (thread_id + 1 == N_THREADS)
      end = DATA_SIZE;

    for (int i = begin; i < end; i++) {
      x_f[i] += y_f[i];
      /*printf("x_f[%d]=%f\ty_f[%d]=%f\tThreadNum=%d\n", i, x_f[i], i,
      y_f[i],
       omp_get_thread_num());*/
    }
  }

  end_time = omp_get_wtime();
  duration = end_time - start_time;

  // Error checking
  for (int i = 0; i < DATA_SIZE; i++) {
    if (!(3.0 - x_f[i]) == 0) {
      printf("ERROR: %f\n", x_f[i]);
      break;
    }
  }
  free(x_f);
  free(y_f);

  printf("==========[FLOAT]==========\n");
  printf("Number of threads: %d\n", N_THREADS);
  printf("Data size: %d bytes\n", DATA_SIZE * sizeof(float));
  printf("ExecTime: %lf ms\n", duration * 1000);

  // ===================== DOUBLE ========================
  double *x_lf = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * DATA_SIZE);
  double *y_lf = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * DATA_SIZE);

  for (int i = 0; i < DATA_SIZE; i++) {

    x_lf[i] = 1.0f;
    y_lf[i] = 2.0f;
  }

  start_time = omp_get_wtime();

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(N_THREADS)
  {
    const int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();

    int begin = range * thread_id;
    int end = begin + range;
    if (thread_id + 1 == N_THREADS)
      end = DATA_SIZE;

    for (int i = begin; i < end; i++) {
      x_lf[i] += y_lf[i];
      /*printf("x_f[%d]=%f\ty_f[%d]=%f\tThreadNum=%d\n", i, x_lf[i], i,
      y_lf[i], omp_get_thread_num());*/
    }
  }

  end_time = omp_get_wtime();
  duration = end_time - start_time;

  // Error checking
  for (int i = 0; i < DATA_SIZE; i++) {
    if (!(3.0 - x_lf[i]) == 0) {
      printf("ERROR: %f\n", x_lf[i]);
      break;
    }
  }
  free(x_lf);
  free(y_lf);

  printf("\n==========[DOUBLE]==========\n");
  printf("Number of threads: %d\n", N_THREADS);
  printf("Data size: %d bytes\n", DATA_SIZE * sizeof(double));
  printf("ExecTime: %lf ms\n", duration * 1000);
  
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT2:** Full table of results
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OrYO.png)

Comment: What computer and which compiler + options do you use?

Comment: i7 10750, I tried both msvc and gcc on Win10 and Ubuntu 20 (Virtual Machine) x64 and x86 but with same results.

Comment: do not invent your own measuring system, however "simple"  you think it will be. It will never give you the right kind of results. I always use  https://github.com/sheredom/ubench.h

Comment: @bogus do not forget to accept one of the answers, so others can see that your question is already answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the code updated Sep 2022.](https://godbolt.org/z/7f8evWdxa) By adding and removing -03 gcc optimizations are switched on and off. Yes, Godbolt will refuse to run from time to time, since that is a large data set for Godbolt. For better benchmarking run locally.

[Here is the code refactored](https://godbolt.org/z/e9f3j5roM). And perhaps meaningful. Using `sheredom/ubench`.
Please spot the compiler arguments: `-fopenmp -s -lm -O3`. Play with `-O` and spot the difference.

(As a side note, please read: [32 OpenMP Traps for C++ Developers](https://pvs-studio.com/en/blog/posts/cpp/a0054/))

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sheredom/ubench.h/master/ubench.h"

#include <assert.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    #define DATA_SIZE 100000
    #define N_THREADS 2
    #define range DATA_SIZE/N_THREADS

static struct {
    float x_f[DATA_SIZE] ;
    float y_f[DATA_SIZE] ;
    double x_d[DATA_SIZE] ;
    double y_d[DATA_SIZE] ;
} * app_data = 0 ;

static void app_start (void) 
{
    app_data = calloc(1, sizeof(*app_data) );
    assert(app_data) ;

  for (int i = 0; i < DATA_SIZE; ++i) {
    app_data->x_f[i] = 1.0f;
    app_data->y_f[i] = 2.0f;
    app_data->x_d[i] = 1.0;
    app_data->y_d[i] = 2.0;
  }
}

UBENCH( omp_measuring, adding_two_arrays_of_floats )
{
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(N_THREADS)
  {
      const int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();

      const int begin = range * thread_id;
      int end = begin + range;
      if (thread_id + 1 == N_THREADS)
          end = DATA_SIZE;

      for (int i = begin; i < end; i++) {
          app_data->x_f[i] += app_data->y_f[i];
      }
  }
}

UBENCH( omp_measuring, adding_two_arrays_of_doubles )
{
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(N_THREADS)
  {
      const int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();

      const int begin = range * thread_id;
      int end = begin + range;
      if (thread_id + 1 == N_THREADS)
          end = DATA_SIZE;

      for (int i = begin; i < end; i++) {
          app_data->x_d[i] += app_data->y_d[i];
      }
  }
}

static void app_end (void) { free(app_data); }


UBENCH_STATE();

int main(int argc, const char *const argv[])
{
    app_start();

    ubench_main(argc, argv);

    app_end();

}
```

### Caveat Emptor

The whole point of OMP is (very) moot since OMP apparently works only if optimizations are not used. It is very hard to beat gnuc `-O3`.

The problem with Godbolt is it chokes on large data sets. On VLA's (aka Very Large Arrays) using OMP *should* appear as meaningful.

In reality, it is very rare to have to deal with megabyte or gigabyte datasets. And then one might imagine GPU's being used. No OMP.

### Bonus

`app_start` is not prescribed by UBENCH. One can pass application command line arguments to a different `app_start` :

```cpp
static void app_start(const unsigned argc, char ** argv )
{
   // use app arguments here
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv) 
{
      app_start(argc,argv);
      ubench_main(argc,argv);
      app_end();
}
```

Comment: I executed this code... and now results seems to be ok. One thing - because in my application to perform tests, i need pass an arguments into program, like in code I shared, but it this case, all inputs are passing to ubench_main(). So, is there any possibility, to pass arguments into application and make data dynamically allocated? And the number of thread could be set as input parameter?

Comment: What is your point to cite "32 OpenMP Traps for C++ Developers"?  Which one applies in this case? Sheredom/ubench seems to be a nice tool. Are confidence intervals are 95%? 1% is unbelievingly accurate....

Comment: @Bogus app_start() and app_end() are not part of `UBENCH`. You can do them however you like or need them. For example, you can pass `main()` arguments to the `app_start(const int, char **) `.Please make the changes on Godbolt and then share the version you are satisfied with or need help with.

Comment: @Laci that is just a pointer to the general advice on OMP.  I avoid OMP for reasons I stated.  `sheredom/ubench` is simple and it works and works on Godbolt too, and that is very nice.

Comment: @Bogus can you vote this as an accepted answer, please?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i analyzed my requirementsonce again and found that I do not need passing argument, setting it before compilation is OK, so Your solution is sufficient. Thanks for all for help!

Comment: *The whole point of OMP is (very) moot since OMP apparently works only if optimizations are not used. It is very hard to beat gnuc -O3.*  That's based on what?  Just this one example of a handful of KB of data that probably all fits in the CPUs fastest cache level?

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced your code on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrRABmGaSvoAMnlqYAHLOAEaYxFyeAA6oQoTmtHaOLu7RsfF0fgHBTmERnJ7GmKYJDATMxARJzq4eRpgmZnRlFQRZQaHhkUblldUpdUK9bf4duV0FAJRGqA7EyBxSOm7%2ByI5YANSabnZOUQB0CNvYmjIAgsur65hbO%2BZDxJjMTsenF9ortGsOm9s2AG7FIjEV7nN4OOLqDa0Z6YIRRZgLDZDdDbfRg87%2BAgbJzMfwQSZvTQAdnRZw2FI2aFoQ0w4iixA2WI2ABEzgAVM4AfQYAEkAFonNwsgoyMXitFvSlUui0%2BmM5mBLnsgASACVsGcWQxtiztJLztKIf5gBsAGI%2BADyHN1G3QsxC7DRGwA9C6qKxUMwCAbyZTqUMmfQNsQ1MBMLq2ZyeQLsC6laqNVqdW4yVLzVaORsAFTiLlUW4sjYQC3W9nZyY4tie5AQOIAL0wqCoJcz7Mr2dZHO5fMFhNT6dLWezAE984Xi0Py5Xcawa3W8I3m62yx2u9He9h%2B2nDRsaIyIMy8BOZM7j391z3Y2eDAZKySd36KXmqJoAKy6PDvou2zj7GSvgOu4UmOr4fl%2Bb4/sKGzaP%2BgFkhSJIskSu72g4jo3EMrRcmYTg3LaqB7Fy4YEFyADuuGYASvpEh8DLMMAuIbIRUQbAioZzg00LODhCCPMw6BCBACbqpq2qEruD7ptKAbYsyBB8U86Bcng6ATixxGYKRCn8cptDONRQEXMBlLMmEwD%2BBOobqDcnY6UpKmokZ0oUsy3gTuZlkGCGYYRs5Ll4AWED2QJjlbHoGycIWtoiUm4nSS5FLubaUZXoKNEmRS%2B7FkeHmYBZtBnrcNgbN4N56HeWykgliUvu%2Bn7fuF%2BjQaB9UQch/nSkh6bdahDrsKV1g4XgeHqURJHkZRhkIXa/U3OgczegkE7eMNo0ALTIsMa1%2BY%2BFJoA42J/BeC2hk0hVGemjwEHMtAbKel3EiyUjTKw0hvvIriyPIqDSDYt4RUIszzPhHycPIBDSHIkzTAA1iAb6eG9UjcJ9UM/dI8hCCAniQ990xwLAMCICgLF4OwZAUBAaB7OTXTAJwjN8OTBDhNjEAhOjpAhP4FQjlzNN4fQlq0Kw/PfaQWC4uo7DSODkt4I8JSAtjEt0sUh2LHI5D0A0XOsHgIShsQI52FgXMEMQI1yy9fB0IwLCyzwduCCIEhc0onAqGGKAA4YBshNjkDTKgUTnarGzrZabiRzQURWHsWMNECCSWNY/SuF73jtDkeTKDEcTnRn%2BfpOdOedPk9SNKUwzF17RQlM0wzl%2BMldYX09g1Mo7cjNkFdcNMQNzAsA8qO9aMS79UjiAAHAAbOtc/cBswDIMgkV/lFEC4IQJDhW4XsbLsUR04yyycJW/0VXoEPozDpDw4jY8o/ITgIzP%2Bxz9ob4AJxvtwnAf4z24MSNw2g/6kC%2BtrKeWMcakDxtDUghMSazAIFEQ65BKA0xPhTZQmB8DAmUPwB2bAODO2IcIMQkgJZkVDFEG2r1x6QK5lPS0h10HYmbBsWeC8l4rzXhvfYW9j6n33hfW%2B%2BNGEv1IG/AB%2Bw3DEm4DIbgb4Z4yE4G%2BbQc9iTaGYZPTGRg4EIJenDBGSNpBuAntAgxxj77I20FYjGUgJHQ2mICYgcQLDcCAA). If the problem is reasonably large e.g. `DATA_SIZE=10000000;` everything works as expected (floats are faster, concurrency reduces runtime). For a modern processor adding 2 arrays of size 1024 is simply to fast and you are just measuring overheads or artefacts...

EDIT: I just changed the order of your code (first double is measured, then float), here is what I got:

```
==========[DOUBLE]==========
Number of threads: 2
Data size: 8192 bytes
ExecTime: 0.091095 ms
==========[FLOAT]==========
Number of threads: 2
Data size: 4096 bytes
ExecTime: 0.001610 ms
```

This proves that whatever you run first is much slower than your second test. I think it is because of cache: OpenMP funcions, data, allocated memory, etc. are already in cache, so your second test runs much faster.

Comment: I know, adding only 1024 elements does not sense, but why there is huge different between float and double? If I test only 1 type of data - float or double, results are a few ms, but when I run program doing both test, first type is a few ms, but second is several time faster. I attached full code and results at my first post.

Comment: "OpenMP functions, data, allocated memory, etc. are already in cache". It's a new process, isn't it?

Comment: @Zoso, No, in the OP's code it is in the same process, even thought `ExecTime` suggests otherwise.

Comment: Interesting thing, i added just only following piece of code: `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(N_THREADS){}` before first piece of code performing vector adding and now it works fine.

Comment: @Laci Oops I didn't see the update and my response was based on the previous version. You're right then. OP definitely had an incorrect way to measure the timings.

Comment: @Bogus, Note that your "solution" (i.e adding `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(N_THREADS){}` ) works only if all compiler optimizations are turned off. If you turn them on this line has no effect (no code will be generated). I recommend using @Chef's suggestion, but if you prefer this instead, please add real code inside `{}`, e.g. initialize the array(s) here...

Comment: I will try to @Chef's solution, because it seems to be much better than mine, but I need to implement passing arguments to the program - data size and threads numbers, because I need to test execution time on each 1-12 threads and on variable data size (12*19 = 228 tests).

Comment: @Laci, sorry to mention it but your Godbolt code is C++ not C.  I assume you just got carried away.

Comment: @Chef you are right, but all the conclusions remain the same in C code too. (I just did it for myself to test the effect.)

Answer (score 0):

The results you show are strange, to be honest. How about you change the for loop to this:

```
for (int i = thread_id; i < DATA_SIZE; i += N_THREADS) { /*  */ }
```

Using this, I got comparable timings with both `float` and `double`.

I couldn't reproduce your results though, because it is not clear how you have defined your `range` variable.

Comment: range is: range = DATA_SIZE / N_THREADS; it is passing as argument to program.